# Call a phtml file at bottom of home page using custom controller Magento 2.2

Tags: module, controllers, magento2.2

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/NameSpace/ReviewRating/Controller/Index/Slider.phtml

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ReviewRating\Controller\Index\Slider;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Slider extends Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
       $resultPage->addHandle('reviewrating_index_slider'); 
       return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/NameSpace/ReviewRating/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <css src="NameSpace_ReviewRating::css/csshome.css"/>
        <script src="NameSpace_ReviewRating::js/jshome.js"/>
  </head>

            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="NameSpace\ReviewRating\Block\Index\Slider" name="custom_layout_load" 
                    template="NameSpace_ReviewRating::reviewrating_index_slider.phtml"
                     cacheable="false"/>
            </referenceContainer>

    </page>
```

> /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/NameSpace/ReviewRating/view/frontend/templates/reviewrating_index_slider.phtml

```
<?php

echo 'Slider content goes here';
```

Comment: Is it necessary to call it using controller? It can be easily done  by appending a block

Comment: if you want slider on home page then your layout file name should be `cms_index_index.xml` instead of `reviewrating_index_slider.xml` Or you can add it from admin

Comment: @Piyush In my  `step 2 ` as above i need to change  `reviewrating_index_slider.xml`  to `cms_index_index.xml`  and there is no need of Slider.php  in controller ?

Comment: Yes, there is no need of controller file if your are adding template to an existing controller action

Comment: @Piyush I changed the name of xml and deleted the Slider.php  and `sudo php bin/magento cache:flush` still no content of phtml is shown

Comment: try removing body tag from xml file

Comment: No sir nothing changed on home page

Comment: @Piyush from `cms_index_index.xml` i addedd css which is working but phtml is not loaded

Comment: @Piyush Thank you sir for your time and support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a controller to show your phtml file on homepage.

Call your phtml file in the footer of your homepage

Create layout file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer" before="-"> 
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="homepage_custom_block" template="Vendor_Module::your_phtml_file.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Your phtml file location

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/your_phtml_file.phtml

Clear your caches.

**Note:** `<referenceContainer name="footer" before="-">` will call your phtml file above footer. If you want to call your phtml file below footer, you can use `<referenceContainer name="footer" after="-">`.

Comment: How to call at bottom of content section before footer not in footer section

Comment: Ok its done using `page.bottom`

Comment: Can you please tell me how we decide the class in block as in above `cms_index_index`

Comment: If you are using any custom block to show some data in your phtml file, so you can use that block as `class="Vendor\Module\Block\CustomBlock"`. And if you are not using any custom block, if you want to call your independent phtml file then you can use Magento's default template class as I have used in the answer. It is `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Comment: @DineshYadav, what is the main difference between <move> , before and  after?

Comment: It is the as same as its name. If you use **before**, your content will move before that particular block and **after** will move it after that block.